# How do I solve this subscript out of bounds error with grofit?

Tags: r

I'm new to R, so this may require a simpler solution than I expect, but I would be very grateful for any help to solve this error.

The current code that I have as follows:

```
time<-read.table("Time (x).csv",header=FALSE,sep=";",dec=".")
time.mat<-data.matrix(time)
data<-read.table("Tumour cell growth (y).csv",header=FALSE,sep=";",dec=".")
data.mat<-data.matrix(data)
Opt1<-grofit.control(smooth.gc=0.5,interactive=FALSE)
grofit(time.mat,data.mat,TRUE)
```

When I run the code, I get the error that says:

Error in data[i, 1:3] : subscript out of bounds

The matrix for data is as follows:

```
     V1
[1,]  6
[2,]  1
[3,]  2
[4,]  3
[5,]  4
[6,]  5
```

The matrix for time is as follows:

```
     V1
[1,]  2
[2,]  1
[3,]  1
[4,]  1
[5,]  1
[6,]  1
```

From this, you can see that the sizes of the matrices are the same.  Can someone please explain to me the following:

1. What i and 1:3 in this error statement mean?
2. How to solve the error (e.g. how to define the dimensions and the values for data if that is indeed needed to solve the error)

Thanks!

Comment: it just means you need more columns. from the argument descriptions, `time` is an `n x m` matrix with n time points and m observations. then `data` is a data frame with `n` columns for each time point *plus* three additional columns. you only have one for each. this is under `?grofit`

Comment: Thank you.  I found that out afterwards and combined the columns afterwards using cbind.  I also found out that I need a minimum of 6 values in order for the fitting to be done successfully; otherwise, it would only run into a error.  Thanks again for your help!